# jquery moving a copy of div animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i've searched for hours on google and here on StackO for this little thing I wanna do but couldn't find an answer, so here it goes:

im building a shopping site. when a person clicks on "add cart" button I want to slide a copy of the img/div to the left and make it disappear after 2 seconds (NOT the original div so it won't break the order of the products). 
How can I accomplish that?

html code:
http://pastebin.com/mMLMP035

Comment: Do you have any existing html you can show us?

Comment: @VIDesignz edited with html source

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
cloneNode();

    });
});

function cloneNode() {
    var itm = document.getElementById("img");
    var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
    var copy = document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(cln);
    $(copy).animate({left: '250px'}); // Animate this tag
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>

<button>Start Animation</button>
<div id="parent">
<div id="img" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```